# Redux toolkit integration over multiple libraries

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

We are diving react app into multiple child libraries, our main product has 4 sub products. So our app is getting large, we are thinking of to divide our app as following:

1. ui-utils - contains all utilities
2. ui-reusable-components- contains all presentational components that are reused across the library
3. ui-{product}-wrapper - contains a specific product related code, reducer slices
4. ui-main - contains entire application code(wrapper for all the libraries).We are thinking of to put redux store here and integrate all reducers. But the problem is ui-{product}-wrapper wants to use store for either purpose of types etc. It cannot because we are not thinking to add ui-main as a dependency for this.

Could any one suggest any better design so that we can appropriately make use of redux store across the libraries.